# Как определить криптовалюту по его кошельку PHP\API?

Tags: php, api

Народ подскажи api или "класс" на php, чтобы можно было определить критовалюту по ее кошельку.
Уже 2 дня шаркаю по но все не могу найти нечего подходящего.
PS/ Не исключаю что не так формулирую вопрос.

Comment: Думаю Вам будет проще посмотреть все примеры кошельков и смотреть, есть ли у них вообще отличия сильные. Возможно их не возможно определить. Если же отличия есть, просто написать всё самому, вообще конечно интересный заказ для фриланс

Comment: Биткоин кошельки начинаются с 1 или 3, где их длина 26-35 символов

Comment: Этериум начинаются с нуля и имеют длинну от 40 до 44 символов

Comment: По аналогии можно определять и другие